# SQL - get all rows in one table created in a time difference of 1 minute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, join

I have a table as:

```
   Id  Ticket_NUM        Date                          Comments
   ==  ==========        ========================      =======
   1       2             2014-08-29 08:44:34.122       a
   2       5             2014-08-29 08:44:34.125       b
   3       3             2014-08-29 08:44:34.137       a
   4       4             2016-08-29 08:44:34.137       b
```

Now, I would like to get Ticket_NUM that are created on the same datetime(2014-08-29 08:44:34.122) with a maximum time difference of < 60 seconds. Can anyone let me know how can we write a query to get this data. I used self join on the table but I'm not getting Ticket_NUM(2, 5, 3) that I'm looking for.

Comment: Please share the query that you wrote that is not producing the desired results.

Comment: so you want to return any tickets that were created within 60 seconds of each other regardless if they were sequential?

Comment: yes, Once I get the records created in that range, I can filter records based on comments

Comment: If they are sequential that would be positive as well

Comment: what version of sql server

Comment: sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be with `LEAD` and `LAG`

```
select * from(
    select 
       *, 
        myFlag = case 
                    when abs(datediff(second,[date],lag([Date]) over (order by [Date]))) < 60 then 1
                    when abs(datediff(second,[date],lead([Date]) over (order by [Date]))) < 60 then 1
                    else 0
                 end
    from yourtable)
where myFlag = 1
order by [Date]
```

You can remove the `where myFlag = 1` to see which ones are flagged.

Or an uglier method:

```
with cte as(
select *, RN = row_number() over (order by [Date])
from yourtable
),

staging as(
    select 
        c.ID
        ,c.Ticket_NUM
        ,c.[Date]
        ,c.Comments
        ,c2DT = min(c2.[Date])
        ,c3DT = max(c3.[Date])
    from 
        cte c
        left join cte c2 on c2.RN = c.RN + 1  --row above
        left join cte c3 on c3.RN = c.RN - 1  --row below
    group by
        c.ID
        ,c.Ticket_NUM
        ,c.[Date]
        ,c.Comments)

select 
    c.ID
    ,c.Ticket_NUM
    ,c.[Date]
    ,c.Comments
from stating c
where abs(datediff(second,c.[Date],c.c2DT)) < 60 or abs(datediff(second,c.[Date],c.c3DT)) < 60
```

Comment: Sure it is, starting with 2012: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: What do you get when you run `select @@version` on that server?  I added a potential alternative.

Comment: All rows that had a record created 60 seconds before or after it regardless of the date

Comment: where you see from yourtable use your table name